# Is there a difference between normal video stream, and a stream made by NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, video-streaming

I'm working on a video streaming project with NodeJS.
In normal situation, If I provide a source like "http://Example.com/video.mp4" to a HTML5 video player, for instance, It doesn't download the whole file into client's browser and then plays it. instead, looks like it gets chunks of data and loads the video.

On the other hand, we have NodeJS streaming process. Which reads a file by streaming and then sends chunks of data to client. I can provide "http://Example.com/stream/:mediaId" to HTML5 player, and in related JS file I do streaming "video.mp4" with Node.

So is there a difference between these two options?

Comment: From the client perspective?  No.  The client doesn't know or care what you run server-side.  Just make sure your Node.js application supports range requests from the clients.

Comment: Thanks. I meant is one of them faster, or more efficient?

Comment: From what perspective?  It isn't really clear what you're getting at or what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I was wondering if streaming with NodeJS makes it faster or something?

Comment: Makes *what* faster?

Comment: Sending video to client side.